# Confusion about the shape of the output logits from Resnet

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am trying to understand why the shape of the output logits from the Resnet18 model I am working with are (27, 19). The shape of 19 I understand, that is the number of classes I have set the model to predict, but the shape of 27 is the part that I am confused about. I have a batch size of 64 so I would have thought the shape of the logits would be (64, 19), because that would give me 1 prediction vector for each image in the batch...

Comment: It should be. Is it possible you've transposed your data somehow so the batch size is being treated as an image dimension and convolved on?

Comment: Ah you know what, its because I was looking at the logits from the last batch in my epoch, and I guess there wasn't enough images left to fill up the entire 64 batch size so it only has 27 images left to train on.

Comment: @SteveAhlswede if so, please post a self-answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the logits from the last batch in my epoch, and there weren't enough images left to fill up the entire 64 batch size so it only has 27 images left to train on.

Comment: You can also accept this as the answer to your question so that the question will not stay unanswered.

Comment: It told me I need to wait 2 days before I can accept an answer I wrote myself

Answer (score 1):

You got it.

The Torch dataloader did this because the method `drop_last` defaults to `False`. If you set it to `True`, it will only output logits shape `(64, 19)`

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Comment: Would there be any cases where setting this to True would be in my interest?

Comment: It depends. Perhaps your data is not balanced all that well and you are sampling with replacement, or you have some weird images that come in at the end by chance, and now you have updated your weights based on just 27 of these images which are maybe not the most representative, when you would have preferred these 27 images to be mixed in with 37 other better images so as to get more generalizable weights.